# JSTL: How to find all links with example.com in href and then append parameter

Tags: jstl

What I need to do is find all links in the xhtml document that contains "example.com" in the href, and then append "?param=value" to all of them.
The links can have different paths, such as:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/path">
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/path/">
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/subsection/path/">
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/somefilename.html">
```

Wanted result is this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/path?param=value">
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/path/?param=value">
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/subsection/path/?param=value">
<a href="http://www.example.com/section/somefilename.html?param=value">
```

My closest effort is this:

```
<c:import url="http://example.com/index.html" var="xhtml"/>   
<c:set var="xhtmlOutput"><x:transform xml="${xhtml}" xslt="${xsltFile}"/></c:set>
<c:set var="aTags" value="${fn:replace(xhtmloutput, '.html', '.html?param=value')}" />
${xhtmloutput}
```

Which is not specific enough, and only targets strings with ".html".
Can this be done with JSTL, and if so, how?

Comment: Some of the formatting did'nt make it. This is the missing part where I state the wanted result:
    <a href="http://www.example.com/section/path?param=value">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/section/path/?param=value">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/section/subsection/path/?param=value">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/section/somefilename.html?param=value">
Also, I see I managed to output the wrong variable. It should say: ${aTags}

Answer (score 0):

I used xsl to do this, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@href[parent::a[contains(@href, 'example.com')]]">
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="."/>?param=value</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I would still like to know if this is possible with jstl.